# Is there a way to ignore a commit in hg blame?

Tags: c++, c, mercurial

I have files with a lot of macros which I want to replace with C++ code with templates.

In doing so, I'll have to change code like this

```
#define stuff_to_do (x) \
   do_some_stuff_##x( );  \
   do_some_more_stuff( x );
```

into

```
template <class T>
void stuff_to_do( T x ) {
       do_some_stuff<T>();
       do_some_more_stuff(); 
}
```

i.e. change tabs/spaces, and escape characters, and small insertions (like `<T>`) here and there.

It is important, however, that the annotations can point to the programmer who did the changes before this.

- Can I make mercurial annotations ignore a particular commit ?
- If not, is there another trick that I could do?

Comment: Changing a macro to a template isn't a whitespace change!

Comment: To blame the template on the person coding the macro would be a lie. The correct way to find blame for the macro is to check blame on the version before the macro to template commit.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck what's the easiest way you could ask hg to give you the one-before-last changeset for a particular line then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to tell `hg annotate` to not show certain commits.  Henceforth people checking "who originally wrote this" are going to have to look "before" this mass change themselves.

Some things that might make that future detective work easier are:

1. do the commit as a non-human user.  Something like `hg commit --user "codeformat bot"` so folks know not to "blame" you
2. leave the old version in place but commented out -- duplicating it and changing the copy rather than changing the original will make it easy to see the original blame info on the commented out lines (provided a block comment is used and is legal in macros...)

Answer (score 4):

[hg annotate](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/hg.1.html#annotate) has some options for this:

```
--skip <REV[+]>
    revision to not display (EXPERIMENTAL)
-w, --ignore-all-space
    ignore white space when comparing lines
-b, --ignore-space-change
    ignore changes in the amount of white space
-B, --ignore-blank-lines
    ignore changes whose lines are all blank
-Z, --ignore-space-at-eol
    ignore changes in whitespace at EOL
-I, --include <PATTERN[+]>
    include names matching the given patterns
-X, --exclude <PATTERN[+]>
    exclude names matching the given patterns
```

The experimental `--skip` option was added in [Mercurial 4.3](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Release4.3).

Comment: You can use `hg annotate --skip desc("#hg-blame-ignore")` to skip changesets where the commit message contains the text "#hg-blame-ignore" (or some other text you prefer), define a [revsetalias](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/revsets), define an [alias](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/hgrc.5.html#alias) like `hg myblame`.